# How to use adb inside Robot Framework script?

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android

I'm testing an application using Android device. I'm using adb-tool to add some text to certain text fields in the application. Here is one example command:

```
adb shell input text "foofas"
```

With above command, I can add text to text field from command line. However, if I try to use that command in my Robot Framework script like this:

```
run process  adb shell input text "foofas"
```

This above won't work anymore. In my understanding, command line command should be working. Error is something like this:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified

Any hints to me?

Comment: It seems the environment from which you are running Robot Framework does not know where adb is. You could provide the full path to adb but better to ensure that the environment from which RF is running has adb in it's path.

Comment: This environment path is not captured in py. Have you try using absolute path ? It should work.

Comment: Hmm. This is very odd problem, because first off all, command adb shell input text "foofas" is working fine from command line. And I'm running Robot Frameworks scripts from same command line.

Secondly, I tried to add following command to my Robot Framework script:

run process    C:\Users\kootjart\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe shell input text "onetwothree"

However, no luck with that.